# can a business delay to bill you

Tags: medical

I thought my insurance was paying for my pt.  but then after i stopped going for a few weeks i got a huge bill in the mail.
is it legal for them to not send a bill (delay billing) for a couple months (waiting till i was absent for a number of weeks)?

Oregon, USA

Comment: In what country?

Comment: Have you checked with your PT and insurance? I've received bills for things insurance wound up covering.

Comment: yes i have called them and they explained my patient portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general legal requirement to present a bill for medical services within, say, 14 day or 1 month of services having been rendered. In Texas, there is a timely-billing requirement that says

> a health care service provider shall bill a patient or other
>   responsible person for services provided to the patient not later than
>   the first day of the **11th month** after the date the services are
>   provided.

The exceptional conditions pertain to billing dates established by insurance contract, and by Medicare / Medicaid rules. There is no analogous rule in Oregon, save for one relating to [workman's compensation](https://wcd.oregon.gov/Rules/div_009/9_16050ub.pdf). Since you have apparently have insurance, this raises the question why the insurance company did not pay for those services. If insurance received but partially rejected a claim (for example paid up to some dollar amount and no more), the hospital would have complied with the Texas law, and after some unspecified period would bill you for the remainder: there is no provision requiring the remainder to be billed within any particular time. However, there is a general statute of limitations past which they cannot collect on the contract: [in Oregon](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/12.080), that is 6 years (from service rendered).